# how to get 26th day of last month and 25th day of current month in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want a query to get results between 26th Day of last month and 25th Day of current month, whenever, this query needs to be executed during any day of month.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Provide your table definition with sample data and expected output, so that it would be easier to produce required results.

Comment: Google oracle date functions -http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html

Answer (score 4):

For 25th Day of current month you can use

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') + 24 FROM dual;
```

For 26th Day of last month you can use

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) + 25 FROM dual;
```

Comment: @PavelGatnar, good question - maybe because it took me only 30 seconds.